# Javascript Show/Hide Div + Add Class on List Items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very large unordered list that currently consists of 256 books that each have an associated list item with a location.

The list item with the associated location of each book are hidden on load, and I would like to figure out the best way so that when each book in the list is clicked, it shows the hidden list item that is associated and also adds an active class. Then if another book is clicked the active class changes to that and the previously shown location is hidden when the new one fades in.

Currently I have some JS that works to do this, although it means that I manually have to list each book and associated location with their own ID each time – meaning that it becomes a really long list and I am sure there is much simpler that to do this.

Below is what I have (HTML)...

```
<ul> 
    <li id="book1">Book Title 1</li>
    <li id="location1" style="display:none;">Book 1's Location</li>

    <li id="book2">Book Title 2</li>
    <li id="location2" style="display:none;">Book 2's Location</li>

    <li id="book3">Book Title 3</li>
    <li id="location3" style="display:none;">Book 3's Location</li>
 </ul>
```

and for the JS...

```
    $("#book1").on('click', function() {

       $("#location1").fadeIn();
       $("#location2,#location3").fadeOut();

       $("#book1").addClass("active");
       $("#book2,#book3").removeClass("active");
   });


   $("#book2").on('click', function() {

      $("#location2").fadeIn();
      $("#location1,#location3").fadeOut();

      $("#book2").addClass("active");
      $("#book1,#book3").removeClass("active");

   });

   $("#book3").on('click', function() {

     $("#location3").fadeIn();
     $("#location1,#location2").fadeOut();

     $("#book3").addClass("active");
     $("#book1,#book2").removeClass("active");

  });
```

All help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to JS and trying to learn. Thanks so much!

Comment: Try using an array and then calling it :)

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywnzo1k8/)**

You can accomplish this by using classes to reference *all* of the elements instead of referencing each element manually with an id.

HTML:

```
<ul> 
    <li class="book">Book Title 1</li>
    <li class="location" style="display:none;">Book 1's Location</li>

    <li class="book">Book Title 2</li>
    <li class="location" style="display:none;">Book 2's Location</li>

    <li class="book">Book Title 3</li>
    <li class="location" style="display:none;">Book 3's Location</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".books").on('click', function() {
    // Remove active class from all book element
    $(".book").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });

    // Fade out any visible location elements
    $(".location").each(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });

    // Add active class to the book element we just clicked on
    $(this).addClass("active");

    // Fade in its respective location element
    $(this).next(".location").fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegation of events with jQuery

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Wrap all elements in a container

```
<ul id="container"> 
    <li class="book">Book Title 1</li>
    <li id="location1" style="display:none;">Book 1's Location</li>

    <li class="book">Book Title 2</li>
    <li id="location2" style="display:none;">Book 2's Location</li>

    <li class="book">Book Title 3</li>
    <li id="location3" style="display:none;">Book 3's Location</li>
 </ul>
```

Then attach one handler for all elements

```
var container = $('#container');
container.on('click', 'li', function(){
    if(container.data('prev'))
        container.data('prev').fadeOut();
    container.data('prev',$(this).next().fadeIn());     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0pm6vav/)

I'd suggest to put location block as sub-element for li, then the following code will work for as many elements as you put on the page:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="book js-book">
        Book Title 1
        <div class="js-location location">Book Location 1</div>
    </li>

    <li class="book js-book">
        Book Title 2
        <div class="js-location location">Book Location 2</div>
    </li>

    <li class="book js-book">
        Book Title 3
        <div class="js-location location">Book Location 3</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$( document ).ready( function ()
{
    var activeClass = 'active',
        sel = {
            book: '.js-book',
            location: '.js-location'
        }

    $( sel.book ).on( 'click', function ( event )
    {
        if ( $( this ).hasClass( activeClass ) )
        {
            return event.preventDefault(); // this code will prevent actions in case you will use <a> tag, or other elements instead of <li>
        }

        $( sel.location ).fadeOut();
        $( sel.book ).removeClass( activeClass );

        $( this ).addClass( activeClass );
        $( this ).find( sel.location ).fadeIn();
    } );
} );
```

CSS:

```
.location {
    display: none;
}
```

Enjoy!